# Packet Tracer help, dropped packets and connectivity issues

Tags: cisco, routing, subnet, packet-tracer, rip

I have set up a network with 3 offices on 3 different subnets.

File available at,
https://github.com/turntheairblue/packetTracer

[image]

Router configuration is as follows,

**R1 - Router**
[image]

**R2 - Router**
[image]

**R3 - Router**
[image]

**ISP - Router**
[image]

I have fully configured Office 1 as labeled in the picture below. Offices 2 and 3 are not fully configured yet, only the routers are configured.

I'm using the laptop in Office 1 to ping each router. I can ping all devices in Office 1 without any dropped packets. I can ping the 172.16.32.1 gateway on the Office 1 router without any dropped packets. I can ping 10.0.0.1 on the Office 1 router without any dropped packets.

Here is the issue, when I ping 10.0.0.2, 11.0.0.2 and 12.0.0.2 on the ISP router, I get 1 reply and 3 dropped packets for each address.

When I ping 11.0.0.1 and 12.0.0.1 I get no replies.

Another thing, if I shut off the 11.0.0.2 and 12.0.0.2 interfaces on the ISP router I can get 4 replies from the 10.0.0.2 interface.

I can't seem to figure out what the cause of this is? Is it something to with my IP addressing scheme? I'm fairly new to networking in general, I'm assuming I have made a noob mistake somewhere along the line!!!

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the router configurations. We cannot simply guess what is incorrectly configured.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the reply. I have uploaded the file to gitHub. https://github.com/turntheairblue/packetTracer

Comment: No. Edit your question with the configurations. Paste the text of the configurations into the question, and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). There are many people here that do not have Packet Tracer, but we need to see the configurations.

Comment: Ok, I have added the configuration of each router so far.

Comment: Please, never ever use images for text. Please paste the text into the question, and use the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). Show the configurations in the terminal (`show running configuration`), copy the text, and paste it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have not used the `no auto-summary` command under your `router rip` configuration. Without that command, RIP assumes that all addressing is classful. It doesn't matter that you have subnetted the `172.16.0.0/16` network; each router assumes that it is directly connected to that network, so it will not route traffic correctly.

Comment: Great, thanks for that! I'm sorry about using screenshots but I'm running packet tracer using WineSkin for Mac. I can't copy and paste text because of this.

Comment: You can. Others do that here with Packet Tracer. I don't have it, so I can't give you exact steps, but people do it all the time.

Comment: Should I use no auto-summary on all four routers?

Comment: Yes. Classful routing is dead. You should use that for RIP, IGRP, and EIGRP.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! Really appreciate it. I can see an option to copy and paste in Packet Tracer CLI now!!! Don't know how I missed it the first time!!! I was trying to copy using 'cmd c' on the mac.